# Move pointer and realloc, C

Tags: c, pointers, realloc

I'm trying to code a buffer for an input file. The Buffer should always contain a defined amount of data. If a few bytes of the data were used, the buffer should read data from the file until it has the defined size again.

```
const int bufsize = 10;
int *field = malloc(bufsize*sizeof(int)); //allocate the amount of memory the buffer should contain
for(i=0;i<bufsize;++i) //initialize memory with something
    *(field+i) = i*2; 

field += 4; //Move pointer 4 units because the first 4 units were used and are no longer needed

field= realloc(field,bufsize*sizeof(int)); //resize the now smaller buffer to its original size
//...some more code were the new memory (field[6]-field[9]) are filled again...
```

Here is a short example of how I'm trying to do it at the moment (without files, because this is the part thats not working), but the realloc() always returns NULL. In this example, the first 4 units were used, so the pointer should move forward and the missing data at the end of the memory (so that it will again contain 10 elements) should be allocated. What am I doing wrong?

I would be very thankful if someone could help me

Comment: `field += 4; //Move pointer 4 units because the first 4 units were used and are no longer needed` and then how are you going to `free` it? "_but the realloc() always returns NULL_", and that's why you should use a temporary variable to be able to `free` `field` in case `realloc` fails.

Comment: You're invoking undefined behavior. The address you're passing to `realloc` is not an address returned from `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`. You can't pass *any* address that happens to be somewhere in the range of a buffer dynamically allocated. It has to be **the** non-NULL address *directly* returned from one of those functions with no modifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`memmove()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html) instead

```
memmove(field, field + 4, (bufsize - 4) * sizeof(*field));
```

you don't need to `realloc()` because you are not changing the size of the buffer, just think about it.

1. If you do this

   ```
   field += 4;
   ```

   now you lost the reference to the begining of `field` so you can't even call `free` on it, nor `realloc()` of course. Read **WhozCraig** comment for instance.
2. Doing `realloc()` for the same size doesn't make that much sense.
3. Using `realloc()` the way you do causes some other problems, for instance when it fails you also run into the same problem, you loose reference to the original pointer.

   So the recommended method is

   ```
   void *pointer;
   pointer = realloc(oldPointer, oldSize + nonZeroNewSize);
   if (pointer == NULL)
       handleFailure_PerhapsFree_oldPointer();
   oldPointer = pointer;
   ```

So the title of your question contains the answer to it, what you need is to move the data from offset `4 * sizeof(int)` bytes to the begining of the pointer, for which `memmove()` is the perfect tool, notice that you could also think of using `memcpy()` but `memcpy()` cannot handle the case of overlapping data, which is your case.

Comment: Well elaborated :) '+1'

Comment: Thanks a lot, very good explanation, i get now what my mistake was

Answer (score 0):

Your problem should be named as Cyclic Buffer.

You should call `malloc()` just once when opening file and once `free()` when you close it.

You don't need to call `realloc()` at all. All is necessary is advaning pointer by amount of read data, wrapping its value around size of buffer and replacing old data with new data from file.

Your problem with `realloc()`: you must pass same pointer to it which was previously returned from `malloc()` or `realloc()` without offsetting it!